# ArFragment displays only blinking screen

Tags: android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I am writing a basic ArCore app. But the ArFragment is displaying a blinking sign only when I place it horizontally to detect plane surface. Also the camera permission is missing when I test it using my Sony experia. I am not sure if my phone is supported because I don't really know the exact model of my phone. Following is my permission and some of the initializing code.

```
//Permission request

public boolean isCameraPermissionGranted(Activity host){
        // if the device isn't compatible return false
        if(!host.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA) &&
                !host.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_AR)){
            return false;
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Permission is not granted
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(host, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            } else {
                // No explanation needed; request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(host, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
        } else {
            // Permission has already been granted
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

//onCreate 
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.image_activity_layout)

        utils  = Utils(applicationContext)
        if(utils.isCameraPermissionGranted(this) && utils.isStoragePermissionGranted(this))
            utils.maybeEnableAr()
        //loadCamera()

        arFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.f_sceneform_fragment) as ArFragment
        // Adds a listener to the ARSceneView
        // Called before processing each frame
        arFragment.arSceneView.scene.addOnUpdateListener { frameTime ->
            arFragment.onUpdate(frameTime)
            //onUpdate()
        }

    }
```

//Manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" android:required="true"/>

//This the fragment
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/f_sceneform_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This is the screen I am seeing.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to manually give it camera permission via app settings on the device?  Also do you have ArCore app installed - either preinstalled or from PlayStore?

Comment: Camera permission is not listed in the permissions. No, I haven't installed ArCore? Is it required with the new Sceneform? If you look at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sceneform-intro/#4 they don't require installing ArCore.

Comment: If you're building a and ARCore app then yes, you need ARCore. If it's not already in your device, then you can search for it in the Play store. To check if your device is supported, then look here : https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added simple permission as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```